# linux g++ regular expressions not working

Tags: c++, regex, linux, g++

I'm trying to find sub string using regular expressions on linux g++.

For example :

```
    std::string logline = "Apr 19 00:55:32 localhost kernel: usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP\n";

    std::string sn = "";
    std::regex re("SerialNumber\: (.*)\n");
    std::smatch match;
    if (std::regex_search(logline, match, re) && match.size() > 1) {
        sn = match.str(1);
    }
    else
    {
        sn = std::string("");
    }
```

it works in windows c++ as well.
but linux g++ not work.
what's is the problem?

Comment: Are you using an old version of gcc? It used to have a non functional regex implementation

Comment: As already said if you use a version of gcc that is 4.8 or older, then this is the reason for your problem, so check your gcc version first.

Comment: yes. used  gcc version is 4.8.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need '\' before ':'. so the correct line is:
`std::regex re("SerialNumber: (.*)\n");` 
with this change your code works with gcc starting gcc 4.9.1. https://wandbox.org/permlink/uuVCxdtpHAjZTghP

Comment: thanks for you help. updated gcc version 4.9.1, it is work as well.

Answer (score 0):

`<regex>` was implemented and released in GCC 4.9.0 so please check your gcc version and see below example:

```
#include <regex> //header  file for regex
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    std::regex r("ab|bc|cd");
    std::cerr << "ab|bc|cd" << " matches ab? " << std::regex_match("sab", r) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ab|bc|cd matches ab? 1
```

Comment: Please format text in your answer. It is barely readable now.

Comment: Hi Kapil. When you receive a request to improve an answer, please consider responding to that request. Readability is important to us here - posts are not just for individual question authors, but every future reader too.

Comment: Sure I will keep in mind while writing any answer in future.